# Sorting circular/periodic intervals

Tags: algorithm, sorting, intervals

I need to find the maximal number of intersections of intervals, i.e for [1,6],[2,5],[5,10],[12,17] the maximal number of intersections is at 5 which is 3.

Now this is easy to do just mark the numbers as begin/end of interval and sort them (in case of tie favor beginning numbers) then traverse the sorted array and keep track of number of beginnings and ends, and the biggest difference between those two is the maximum.

On the example the array would be (1 beg,2 beg,5 beg,5 end,6 end,10 end,12 beg,17 end)

And at 5 there are 3 begins and 0 ends.

Now my problem is that my intervals are circular/periodic, for example if the intervals are contained in [0,1] then 1 is equal to 0 (like going full circle and returning to the same point)  the interval [0.7,0.3] can be imagined as union of [0.7,1] and [0,0.3] so it's different from [0.3,0.7].

The approach fails since for example the first number may be end number.

Comment: Why not break intervals in which the first number is greater than the second into two intervals (as you did) and then proceed with your original algorithm with the revised interval set?

Comment: @Jiminion I'd have one end point and one start point and they would cancel each other.

Comment: Count the number of such special intervals (i.e. that have a begin value greater than the end value) and let this number be your initial value for the number of beginnings (instead of zero). Now you can treat the special intervals just like any other in your algorithm and find the correct answer.

Comment: @trincot That's perfect, can't believe I haven't thought of that. Feel free to post an answer I'll gladly accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could count the number of such special intervals (i.e. those that have a begin value greater than their end value) and let this number be your initial value for the number of beginnings (instead of zero).

Now you can treat the special intervals just like any other in your algorithm and find the correct answer.